# Does a BMS reduce the quality of the output of batteries?

Tags: amplifier, audio, bms

I plan to build a high quality headphone amplifier. It does not use much power (<1A) so I think about using 18650 batteries as power supply. I am pretty sure these batteries should be a very smooth power supply without any ripple or spikes, etc.

But how about if I add a BMS to the batteries. Does a BMS have a negative influence about the power output? Will the BMS possibly produce ripple, spikes, or other unwanted power problems?

I don't plan to charge the batteries at the same time when the amp is on. When I use the amplifier any external power to charge the batteries will be disconnected.

Comment: Batteries change voltage over time as they discharge. And over-discharging them will damage the batteries, too.

Comment: BMS is about safety. It protects the battery, the device, humans holding the device from getting burns, and buildings from burning down. Why omit it? Most likely you need audio measuring equipment worth of a new car to find a difference in the audio quality. There are lots of other ways to end up with bad quality audio but I don't see the BMS being an issue.

Comment: 18650's almost always have a cell protection circuit (for one or two cells in series) or BMS (for multiple cells). It won't degrade the power in any way.

Answer (score 1):

> Does a BMS have a negative influence about the power output? Will the
> BMS possibly produce ripple, spikes, or other unwanted power problems?

Yes, but only if you try to draw too much current from it. Get a BMS with much higher current rating than your amp draws and it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks. It seems the amp will use less than 500mA. And the smallest BMS which I could find has a rating of 4A.